# Using subgraph() and preserving vertex attributes with igraph python

Tags: python, igraph, subgraph, vertex-attributes

I want partition my disconnected graph into blocks (to use community_spinglass). However once I get the subgraph and use community_spinglass() the labels of the vertex in the original graph are lost. I am dealing with 40+ vertices so it is not easy to track them down. Here is a "toy example" of my problem:

```
import igraph
from igraph import Graph
g4_matrix = [ [0,0,-1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0.8,0.2,0,0], [-1,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0.8,0,0,1,0,0.1], [0,0.2,0,1,0,-0.3,-.7], [0,0,0,0,-0.3,0,1], [0,0,0,0.1,-0.7,1,0] ]
v_name = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
g4 = Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(g4_matrix, mode = 'undirected',attr = 'weight' )
igraph.plot(g4,bbox = (300, 300),vertex_label = v_name)
```

[image: Original graph with labels]

After I obtain blocks and communities:

```
g4_blocks = g4.blocks()
g4_block = g4.vs.select(g4_blocks[1])
Block1 = g4.subgraph(g4_block)
igraph.plot(Block1, bbox = (200, 200), vertex_label = v_name)
```

[image: Subgraph, as observed the vertices follow v_name list in order and don't preserve past label]

But we see the vertices follow v_name list in order, not their previous label.Furthermore when we obtain communities:

```
comm = Block1.community_spinglass()
for c in comm:
    print c

[2, 3, 4]
[0, 1]
```

we get the index of the subgraph, but it is difficult to relate to the index of original graph.

Is there a way to obtain communities referring to the index or label of the original graph?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Block1.vs[c]["name"]` to get the names of the nodes in community `c` within `Block1`. Explanation:

1. `Block1.vs` is the vertex sequence of the entire `Block1` graph.
2. `Block1.vs[c]` subsets this vertex sequence to only the nodes whose indices are in the iterable named `c`, which is the case in your for loop.
3. `Block1.vs[c]["name"]` retrieves the `name` vertex attribute of the vertices that you have selected in the previous step. Since names are kept in the subgraphs, this should allow you to relate the nodes of `Block1` back to your original graph.

Comment: I get the error: ' KeyError: 'Attribute does not exist' ' .

Comment: Ah, use `g4.vs["name"] = v_name` first - this will copy your `v_name` list into the `name` vertex attribute of your original graph. `Block1` will then keep the names correctly.